# Do I need a service account for every user of my web app which uses Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a web app that I have created. The app allows a user to upload very large data files to Google Cloud Storage and from there the files are loaded into BigQuery. On my web app front end, the user logs in and then hits an upload button where he/she selects a file which is then uploaded accordingly to GCP. I previously used a service account and only had one client so this wasn't an issue. However, now I have several extra clients wanting to use the same app.

In the Google documentation it advises to make use of service accounts whenever possible and hence I have gone down that route. However, now that I have a mix of clients I cannot find a way to separate them to avoid one user of a client having access to another clients data. This is because they would both be using the same service account and this makes sense.

Is there a method to link a service account to the login authentication specific users of my app (using Firebase but open to other methods)? This way I could set permissions for each of the service accounts and then link respective users from each company to a single service account.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Based on the information in your question, I would not use service accounts for theses users. I would use Google Accounts (OAuth 2.0) and give the user a Cloud Storage scope to upload data. Another, possibly better/secure method, is to use Signed-URLs for uploading to Cloud Storage.

Comment: In addition, you are limited to 100 service accounts per project. It's definitively not the solution. The services accounts are designed for machine to machine communication. Here you are more in a "authorization management" use case. I recommand to have a database, Firestore/datastore if you prefer serverless and document oriented, or cloud sql if you prefer the relational database. Thus you will be able to keep the link between files and users.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the response. I believe I better look into OAuth2.0 then. My issue with signed URL's is that the users need to be able to also view the data and make requests for data which would run queries in my Flask backend. In addition, if two users are form the same client, I would like them to both be able to view the same data at the same time.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for answering. I completely forgot about the limit of 100 service accounts! I use Firestore for logging into my webapp. I will have to consider how to use it to then map IAM roles for specific objects in Cloud Storage.

Comment: [https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user] gave some use-cases where Authentication as an end-user is preferred over using a service account. One example is accessing datasets that belong to a user of your application. I believe that the emphasis on using Service accounts in almost every situation is misleading IMO, as many applications these days revolve around datasets that should be protected.